# Eigen with CPPUTest?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, eigen, cpputest

I am having a problem when trying to use CPPUTest to test my library.

Everything was fine until i included Eigen library to handle matrix processing.
When i tried to build with g++, Eigen library kept throwing errors:

- /eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:270:41 error: 'ptr' does not name a type
- /eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:1655:12 error: expected type-specifier before 'static_cast'
- /eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainOBjectBase.h:137:5 error: declaration of 'operator new' as non-function

If Eigen or CPPUTest runs separately, no error is output.

My guess is the two libraries have conflicts at some point.

Really need some helps here. Big thanks.

**Edit 1:**
This is my Makefile:

> CXX = g++ -std=c++0x -lstdc++ CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -static
>   -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -I./ -I$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include LDFLAGS = -L./ -L$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/lib -lCppUTest -lCppUTestExt -pthread CPPUTEST_HOME = ./cpputest/workspace/install USER_CFLAGS = -I
>   /usr/local/include/eigen3 TARGET = MyLibrary SRCS = MyLibrary.cpp
>   MyLibraryTest.cpp OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)   all: $(TARGET)   $(TARGET):
>   $(OBJS)   $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)   $(OBJS): $(SRCS)
>     $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^   %.o: %.cpp   $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<
>   .PHONY: clean clean:  rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS) *.gcno *.gcov *~    find .
>   -name "*.gcda" | xargs -r r

Comment: Can you specify which version of Eigen and CPPUTest you're using? A full [mcve] would also be helpful...

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of both libraries: Eigen 3.3.1 and CPPUTest 3.8

Comment: Can I see the command line used to build the .cpp file that triggered these errors?

Comment: Did you try including Eigen before CPPUTest?

Comment: Yes, i did. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem if I include Eigen before including CppUTest (also see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that CppUTest defines a macro `new`:
https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/blob/master/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h#L76

When I `#include <Eigen/Core>` before `#include <CppUTest/TestHarness.h>`, I don't get the error you reported (did no further testing, though). Alternatively, you can `#undef new` after including CppUTest or define `CPPUTEST_MEM_LEAK_DETECTION_DISABLED` before including CppUTest (that will of course disable leak detection).

The offending line in Eigen is using the placement-new operator (i.e., it does not allocate memory itself), and it's syntax is what throws CppUTest's `new` macro off.